# "RNGestureHandlerRootView" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-gesture-handler

I need to fix this error.

Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNGestureHandlerRootView" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
in StackView (created by StackView)
in StackView
in Unknown (created by Navigator)
in Navigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SwitchView)
in SwitchView (created by Navigator)
in Navigator (created by NavigationContainer)
in NavigationContainer (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer

Comment: Can you share your project's configuration files?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Recently I had the same problem. Here's the solution:

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler
```

and

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

On the root of the Project, the App.js file probably.

Try to use the documentation, it can be found here, and it's how I resolved this issue:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

Comment: I have done as mentioned by you, but still not able to solve this issue. any further help you can do?

Comment: Doing this solved my issue, but still unclear why this component is required when I have not used it in my app at all. Is this an issue with React Native Expo

Comment: I am using bare React Native Project and I have added the import section on my App.tsx but still the issue is not resolved. Still getting the same error message :-(

Answer (score 16):

### 1. Update dependencies with expo

On an existing `Expo project` some dependencies versions installed by you may be incompatible with Expo. This causes such errors. To fix this issue you need the right versions of those dependencies. Run the following command to remove the incompatible versions and install the supported versions as required by Expo.

```js
expo update
```

Confirm the action with `Y` if it prompts your approval. Then restart your app. This will fix the issue.

### 2. Install required dependencies

If you don't have `react-native-gesture-handler` installed in your project, install it.

- If you install it with `expo` you may not require to follow the step 1 above.

```js
expo install react-native-gesture-handler
```

- But if you install it through `npm` or `yarn` you also need to follow the step 1 above.

```js
npm install react-native-gesture-handler
```

- To import it in `App.js/ App.tsx`, place it in the first line of the file, or use as required:

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Comment: the part about using expo to install.  thx!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i had to clear cache by runing:

```
expo start --clear
```

After trying the other solutions and not working.

Answer (score 0):

react native error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/czCTX.png

sole my side this code

expo install react-native-gesture-handler

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer already given: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398125/5468463. Why do you repeat?

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found out if you are using expo ,run the command line expo update in your terminal. It fixes all the wrong dependencies and installs the correct packages.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me -
i have delete all the node modules

```
$ npm install -g remove-node-modules
```

then insalled it again

```
 $ npm install
```

Comment: Why do you think this solved the problem?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson He might have some modules duplicated. By deleting he is cleaning up/removing the duplicated modules (react-native-gesture-handler).

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps to install dependencies with `expo install` and put the "import" line in `App.js`, I realized this still doesn't work in previously built standalone app. However, it works in Expo Go.

The error is from RN Fabric not able to recognize the native component, as it's not registered in the `UIManager` from the native side. To do that a new build of native code is required. I assume that's why previously built standalone app won't work. However, I am not sure why the Expo Go app would work -- one possible reason is that those dependencies are pre-bundled to the Expo Go native app already.